# Going through multidimensional lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have who lists:

```
list_a = [['abc', 10],['def', 20],['ghj', 30]]
list_b = [['abc', 40],['def', 50],['ghj', 60],['klm', 70]]
```

and I want to go through list.b with list.a so I can remove the spare element "list.b[3]" and calculate with list members:

```
list_a[0][1] - list_b[0][1] = -30
list_a[1][1] - list_b[1][1] = -30
list_a[2][1] - list_b[2][1] = -30
```

What on earth I should do?

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip`.  It will automatically trim to the length of the shortest iterable. Here it is in a list comprehension:

```
[a_val[1] - b_val[1] for a_val, b_val in zip(a,b)]
```